# What is the difference between 7100, 16700 and 18300 hashcat modes?

Tags: hashcat

Studying how expensive and how long it takes to brute force macOS Catalina and Big Sur passwords (if possible on T2/M1 Macs).

My (likely naive) understanding is that macOS uses PBKDF2-SHA512 to hash passwords.

Why 3 modes?

Comment: Can you link to those hashcat modes? https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat#supported_attack_modes because the documentation shows what each of those modes is for

Comment: `7100` => macOS v10.8+ (PBKDF2-SHA512), `16700` => FileVault 2, `18300` => Apple File System (APFS)

Comment: Right, so, there you go?

Comment: @schroeder Doing some research for a series on passwords that will be published on the [privacy guides](https://www.youtube.com/sunknudsen) and would love to pick your brain. Can we [connect](https://sunknudsen.com/contact)?